Grafana - Filter logs by time for alerting purposes
I'm only new to the world of Grafana after working in Splunk for many years within a devops capacity. I apologise if this question is below standard here, but I'm pretty stuck at the moment.
I want to add a time filter to my query, so I can have 2 separate queries which can be evaluated separately for alerting purposes. This is because during the night we see much less traffic on our platform, so hopefully I can stop waking people up unnecessarily!
I'm using Grafana V9 5.15
Data source is Loki
Query
sum by(http_statuscode) (count_over_time({job="apps/xy-connect"}
|~ (?i)logger="Esf.AspNetCore.Logging.Middleware.LoggingMiddleware"
|~ (?i)canonical-log
|~ (?i)UISJ.+
| logfmt
| http_path =~ .+payments/.+/capture [$__interval]))
I tried implementing a time filter as below which didn't work as I expected
| time(8:00:00<t<20:00:00)'
| range(time(8h))...(time(20h))

You can configure silences in grafana
